# How to configure site created in drupal on some other machine to be run on localhost of another machine

Tags: drupal-6

I would be working on a site created in drupal by someone and I want to run that site on my machine through localhost.

Plss help me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To run a Drupal site on your local machine, you will need the following things:

1. Export file of Drupal database which you can import into phpymyadmin.
2. All the dump of Drupal files which you will put up in your Xampp or wamp or Lamp depending  upon your OS.
3. Then update the settings.php file in sitename/sites/default folder and change the Db name and username and pwd for mysql.
4. Also check the root folder if there is .htaccess file. If it is already there, then its fine, otherwise you can copy it from fresh drupal download and put into your root folder.

Finally type in your browser localhost/site_name and you are ready to go.